# Accepting prompt alert on rebooting router via PhantomJS - Selenium, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs

My code for rebooting TP-Link router :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\\Users\\example\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\phantomjs.exe')
browser.get("http://admin:admin@192.168.0.1")
browser.get("http://192.168.0.1")

browser.switch_to.frame("bottomLeftFrame")

system_tools_element = browser.find_element_by_id("a43")
system_tools_element.click()

reboot_menu_element = browser.find_element_by_id("a49")
reboot_menu_element.click()

browser.switch_to_default_content()
browser.switch_to.frame("mainFrame")

reboot_button = browser.find_element_by_id("reboot")
reboot_button.click()

#code that I found on one of the stack answers for accepting alert. This code doesn't work and it does not reboot the router.

browser.execute_script("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }")

browser.close()
```

I have successfully tested the code using Chrome driver and I used

```
alert = browser.switch_to.alert
alert.accept()
```

to accept the alert.

PhantomJS give following error on using this `browser.switch_to.alert.accept()`

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Invalid Command Method - {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"53","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:62839","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"sessionId\": \"d8059740-d022-11e7-9baa-b725394efad6\"}","url":"/accept_alert","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"accept_alert","directory":"/","path":"/accept_alert","relative":"/accept_alert","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/accept_alert","queryKey":{},"chunks":["accept_alert"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/d8059740-d022-11e7-9baa-b725394efad6/accept_alert"}
```

***My question is :-***
Is there any way to make PhantomJS work in this case, that is, accept alerts?

I am new to programming itself so a little bit detailed answer will be more helpful :)

Comment: I am not sure if I have understood your question correct, but whats wrong with `browser.switch_to.alert.accept()` through `PhantomJS`? Are you seeing any error? What does the error says? Update the complete error in the Question area along with the relevant HTML.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Phantom JS driver is a Remote WebDriver that uses PhantomJS as back-end. As PhantomJS is pure JS you can make use `execute_script` of selenium python bindings.

```
browser.execute_script("window.alert = function(){}");
browser.execute_script("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");
```

This checks for any alert in a page and accepts it.

Comment: no luck. the code runs perfectly without any errors but the router is not rebooting which means the alert code is not working.

Comment: @TheOne paste these lines before the alert could come up. Once these lines are run, alerts will be accepted by default.

Comment: did as you told.But yet again the code works without any error but router is not rebooted. Anyway I found way around using headless chrome. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is a timing issue and you have to induce `ExplicitWait` i.e. **`WebDriverWait`** for the `alert` to appear as follows :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present)
browser.execute_script("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");
```